# Duda sobre else dentro de un foreach

Tags: php, foreach, else

Señores un saludo cordial.

Buscando, encontré en la red un script php que me permite buscar archivos en un directorio, hice un ajuste para que me busque solo archivos pdf y me muestre un enlace para descargarlo, este ya funciona bien, Pero quisiera mostrar un **`echo`** de error si no se encuentra el archivo, no he podido ubicar bien el echo para que no se repita.

```
        <?php

        // Ruta del directorio donde están los archivos
        $path  = 'C:\wamp\www\buscador'; 

        // Arreglo con todos los nombres de los archivos
        $files = array_diff(scandir($path), array('.', '..')); 

        // Obtienes tu variable mediante GET
        $code = $_GET['codigo'];

    foreach($files as $file){
        // Divides en dos el nombre de tu archivo utilizando el . 
        $data          = explode(".", $file);
        // Nombre del archivo
        $fileName      = $data[0];
        // Extensión del archivo 
        $fileExtension = $data[1];

        if($code == $fileName){
            echo "<a href = '$fileName.pdf' >Descargar certificado</a>";
            break;  // Realizamos un break para que el ciclo se interrumpa
    }    
} 

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes crear una variable que te indique si se ha encontrado o no el fichero que estas buscando. Creas la variable con un valor inicial de False y  en el caso que encuentres el fichero lo pones a true.
La comprobación de la variable lo haces fuera del bucle para que no se repita el mensaje.

```
        <?php

    // Ruta del directorio donde están los archivos
    $path  = 'C:\wamp\www\buscador'; 

    // Arreglo con todos los nombres de los archivos
    $files = array_diff(scandir($path), array('.', '..')); 

    // Obtienes tu variable mediante GET
    $code = $_GET['codigo'];
    $existFile = false;


foreach($files as $file){
    // Divides en dos el nombre de tu archivo utilizando el . 
    $data          = explode(".", $file);
    // Nombre del archivo
    $fileName      = $data[0];
    // Extensión del archivo 
    $fileExtension = $data[1];

    if($code == $fileName){
        $existFile = true;
        echo "<a href = '$fileName.pdf' >Descargar certificado</a>";
        break;  // Realizamos un break para que el ciclo se interrumpa
    }    
}
if ($existFile == false){
     echo "<p> No se ha encontrado el fichero </p>";         
}
```

?>

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Excelente, esa era la solución, muchas gracias IDanny7

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente el lugar para pintar un `echo` de error sería en un `else` añadido al `if` que pinta el enlace si el contenido de `$code` es igual al contenido de `$fileName`. Quedaría algo así:

```
if($code == $fileName){
    echo "<a href = '$fileName.pdf' >Descargar certificado</a>";
    break;  // Realizamos un break para que el ciclo se interrumpa
}
else {
    echo '<p>Error al cargar el fichero</p>';
}
```

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias PHPMyguel. Eso ya lo intenté, el problema es que por cada recorrido que hace el foreach me muestra el error y al final si me muestra el enlace para descargar el archivo, no funciona como quisera, o que muestre el error una sola vez o que muestre el enlace de descarga del archivo, pero así como lo propones muestra ambos mensajes cuando el archivo existe y cuando no existe muestra varias veces el error.

Comment: Entiendo. Entonces una buena manera de hacerlo es como te propone el compañero @lDanny7, usando una variable de control que "active" el mensaje de error y mostrarlo tras finalizar el bucle dependiendo del valor de esta variable.